# Class 'Role' not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I am creating a custom user package for use in Laravel 4.

I am running in to a little difficulty setting up my relationship in the User model. Here is the relationship:

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Role');
}
```

Now, for some reason this is resulting in a Class 'Role' not found error. Everything in src/models gets auto-loaded via composer in the composer.json file for that package:

```
"classmap": [
        "src/migrations",
        "src/controllers",
        "src/models",
        "src/repositories"
    ],
```

Any suggestions?

(I have tried the obvious composer dump-autoload, composer update etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return $this->belongsToMany('Role');` is just a string

so you needed the full path like this:

`return $this->belongsToMany('path\to\Models\Role');`

Comment: Ah cheers, but I figured out just before you posted. I will accept your answer though as it is correct :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I managed to figure it out, I needed to reference the full namespace of the Role model in the relationship as per the below:

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Vendor\Package\Model\Role');
}
```